# Open IBM Sametime chat window programmatically

Tags: java, chat, lotus-notes, sametime

Consider a scenario where Sametime chat is already running. It is possible open chat with another person from another program? Can you please tell me the procedure?

Thanks a lot,
Omkar

Comment: Do you mean as a plugin for Sametime? Or as a separate application which is using the Sametime API?

Comment: Separate application which will use Sametime API...

Comment: Or another way is interprocess communication with Sametime.. Is it posssible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're asking is possible, but your question isn't clear.  Perhaps you can expand on what your final goal is.  Sametime has data channels, IM channels and all sorts, and lots of things are possible with the different toolkits.

Most likely from your question, you can do this using the web connect API, which is documented in the sametime SDK.  It would involve making a HTTP request from your application that wants to launch a chat window to the HTTP server that is running within the Sametime client.

Comment: Thanks Carl.. I will give example. If I am logged in on samtime on my comp and say I want to chat with Jack. I should open that window using another program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK in that case I'm correct, your other program can communicate with the running Sametime connect client using the Sametime Web Connect API.  You can find the documentation for the API in the Sametime SDK, which is here: http://epil.io/744k0

For example, if the user has sametime connect running, a call to the following URL: http://localhost:59449/stwebapi/chat?userId=john@acme.com  would open a Sametime IM window to john@acme.com

Comment: Hi Karl, I could not find localhost:59449 running on my machine. How can I find which port is being used by SameTime chat?

Comment: Hi Carl, Thanks I could manage to open the chat window.. But along with that I get log of the chat and windows asks me to save that chat log. How to stop that? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I am extending carl's answer so please give credit to Carl.

1. Install IBM Sametime 8.5 or above SDK
2. Goto Notes\framework\rcp and open plugin_customization.ini
   Set com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.webapi/startWebContainer=true
3. Restart the Lotus notes and sametime
4. Write this C# program

   var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:59449/stwebapi/chat?userId=kt816") as HttpWebRequest;

   request.GetResponse();

Let me know it any quesions

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this document](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/ST30/%24File/stlinkstk.pdf).  In it, I found this:

```
 <HEAD>  
      <TITLE>Sametime Links Sample Page</TITLE>  
      <LINK REL=STYLESHEET  HREF="http://sametime.acme.com/sametime/stlinks/stlinks.css" TYPE="text/css">  
      <SCRIPT src="http://sametime.acme.com/sametime/stlinks/stlinks.js">  </SCRIPT>
      <SCRIPT> setSTLinksURL("http://sametime.acme.com/sametime/stlinks");</SCRIPT
 </HEAD>
```

Which you can add this body:

```
<body>
<script>writeSTLinksApplet("","",false); </script>
<Script>writeSametimeLink("<username>", "Click here to IM Name!", true)</Script>
</body>
```